# RazorPage executes 2 times, rendering visitor's counter useless

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a Website with RazorPages and need to implement a visitor's counter. My idea for the counter is very simple, I created a .json file with just one property with an initial value of 0, like so:

```json
{
   "NumberOfViews":0
}
```

The idea is to read the file, deserialize it to a model, increase it by one (++) every time the page loads and save the state, like so:

```cs
//Constructor
public MyStartModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IStoredPagesService storedPagesService)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _pagesService = storedPagesService;

    string myCookies = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("appdata/appcookies.json");
    var opt = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    AppCookiesModel appData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppCookiesModel>(myCookies, opt);
    ViewsNumber = ++appData.NumberOfViews;
    string appDataJSON = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(appData);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("appdata/appcookies.json", appDataJSON);
}

public UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager { get; }
public IStoredPagesService _pagesService { get; }



public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    string message = await _pagesService
        .GetPagesByAuthorIDAsync(_userManager.GetUserId(User));
    string allPosts = await _pagesService
        .GetPostsByAuthorIDAsync(_userManager.GetUserId(User));

    Pages = JsonSerializer.Deserialize< List<WebPage> >(message, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    Posts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize< List<WebPost> >(allPosts, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
}
```

The problem is that for some reason that I ignore, the contructor() and the OnGetAsync() methods get called 2 times, so the counter increase by 2 every time.

Any ideas?
PD: I created a new and empty RazorPages project just to test my code an it works just fine! So, there must be something in the code above...

Comment: Open up the developer console and monitor network requests. There has to be a second request to your API.

Comment: As you said, checking the network showed that the RazoPage got called 2 times. But how can I identify who is doing the second call?

Comment: Take a look at `Initiator` tab, it should show you the stack trace of where the request is sent from. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-80/#initiators

Comment: I am using Firefox but I could find that it is the same page who is doing the call. I don't know how, because apparently the only two methods called are the constructor and the OnGetAsync(). When I debug it line by line, it finish the OnGet an jumps to the Contructor again... Crazy

Comment: It's even easier to find it in Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H5eU.png

Comment: Also, you shouldn't increment the view count in the constructor, do it in `OnGetAsync`. Or implement an action filter if you like. You probably want to deduplicate views from the same user, and allow 1 view per 10s for example. For that, you can simply use an `ICache` and check if the user has a previous view within last 10s or else increment the count.

Comment: A second problem is race conditions, if two request comes at the same time, and reads the last count as `14` before one has a chance to increment it, both request will try to change that to `15` when it should have been `16`, and overwrite each other's results. That's why you need to use a proper solution to handle concurrency, like a database, or redis, or a simple ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: Originally the 'counter' code was located inside OnGetAsync(), but when I found the problem I moved it to the Constructor. I put it back inside Get() now... still same result.
Thanks to you, I was able to trace the 'initiator' of the call being the same RazorPage (it is calling to itself). Like I said: "New project, same 'counter' code, works fine".
I am going to have nightmares tonight...

Comment: Do you have an empty img/script tag in HTML that's trying to load the same page?

Comment: Hey! I am falling asleep, here is 5 am. I think I will continue with this tomorrow. Couldn't find any img/script tag... maybe I am just too tired, thanks!